# How to access com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmSmsDispatcher instance?

Tags: android, reflection

I need to access com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmSmsDispatcher's **sendRawPdu** method.

I've done a little research and found that *GSMPhone* class contains *GsmSmsDispatcher* instance. I hoped to obtain *GSMPhone* instance from *PhoneFactory* but it seems to be uninitialized (it's static variables are *null*).

Android API version >= 8.

Comment: Perhaps you should state what functionality you wish to accomplish; that way someone may be able to suggest a workable method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access Android's internal classes using reflection. Each application in Android runs in its own process with its own instance of the Dalvik VM. Classes loaded in one process are not visible to another process. So when you try to access static variables from PhoneFactory, you end up loading the PhoneFactory class with *unintialized variables*.

Your best will be to do whatever you want to get done using the Android APIs. There are a few ways to get access to some private Android services, but it won't get you too far. The only relevant one for SMS is the **isms** service. You can look through the methods available in it in the ISms.aidl file present in the com.android.internal.telephony package.