# how import com.android.internal.telephony.gsm

Tags: android, telephony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.GsmSmsDispatcher instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014317/how-to-access-com-android-internal-telephony-gsm-gsmsmsdispatcher-instance)

Sorry, I'm new developer on android and I don't understand how import and invoke com.android.internal.telephony.gsm.  I tried "import com.android.internal.telephony.gsm" bur it cannot be resolved. (now I use API 10) What I need to do?
Can u help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this following link. It's solved there .. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7014317/how-to-access-com-android-internal-telephony-gsm-gsmsmsdispatcher-instance

Answer (score 2):

It is an internal class and you are not supposed to use it. To make sure, the SDK specifically excludes the internal classes so to make it work you have to hack the sdk and make a fake target. Then you can use reflection to create the correct class. However, even if you do so, you are probably doing this to access internal Phone class information and you will be unable to do so as the access remains restricted to callers that call from the correct thread.

In the event of success, your code would likely break on the next release.

Answer (score 1):

DOn't use it, use the original class that is available in android. Telephony, not the GSM one. You introduce a lot of risk when change occurs.

**DONT DO IT!**